# hide and show ul based on id

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to toggle display block or none based on a string I have onload?

If my HTML is as follows

```
<ul id="test1,test2" style="display:none;"> 
<li><a href="#" onclick="myfunction('users')">My Link</a></li> 
</ul>

<ul id="abc1,abc2" style="display:none;"> 
<li><a href="#" onclick="myfunction('users')">My Link</a></li> 
</ul>
```

**Is it  possible to achive with class="test1 test2" and based on this can i get ul id and toggle it ? If id cannot have multiple values.**

i will get the text test1 or abc2 or abc1. I want to find this ul on this text and i want to set it to display : block Please help me on this

Comment: When? What event should toggle?

Comment: Onload of page i will get the text like abc1 or abc2 or test1. Based on this text i want to search the ul id and set it to display : block;

Comment: Yes i am using jquery

Comment: @MohammedFarooq check my answer for hiding with multiple classes $(".test1.test2").show() will show that particular ul

Comment: id="test1,test2" ??? its not allowed have multiple id's like that...

Answer (score 2):

You can't have multiple IDs separated by commas in the ID tag

```
<ul id="test1,test2" style="display:none;"> 
<li><a href="#" onclick="myfunction('users')">My Link</a></li> 
</ul>

<ul id="abc1,abc2" style="display:none;"> 
<li><a href="#" onclick="myfunction('users')">My Link</a></li> 
</ul>
```

id can have only one value. ID is not class to have multiple values. That too with comma

So once you modify the code with multiple classnames like below

```
<ul class="test1 test2" style="display:none;"> 
<li><a href="#" onclick="myfunction('users')">My Link</a></li> 
</ul>

<ul class="abc1 abc2" style="display:none;"> 
<li><a href="#" onclick="myfunction('users')">My Link</a></li> 
</ul>
```

In case you know the classnames already:

```
    $("ul.test1.test2").show();
```

Add the above line to your click handler or if you want to do it in onload then

```
$(function() {
       $("ul.test1.test2").show();
})
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/yaxoj/1/edit)**

Comment: ok can i have class="test1 test2" and based on this can i get ul id and toggle it ?

Comment: I have changed the code, Now pass the id text1 or abc1 to the function and it will display that block

Comment: How to do it with class?

Comment: @mplungjan I thought a generic function would be best in this case. Else the user need to copy paste the same lines of code everywhere. So instead pass the classname and the function will do the part.

Comment: OP needs it onload and it is a one-liner

Comment: The end solution is identical to mine.

Comment: @mplungjan I don't know why you are saying $(".test1.test2") is wrong syntax. BTW your solution hides only blocks with class test1 and if the user wants to hide blocks with multiple class names for a single block, then your solution will not work.

Comment: @mplungjan Here is the proof that its correct syntax : http://jsbin.com/yaxoj/1/edit

Comment: I corrected my comment. I believe I completely answered the question since OP has ONE string but may have multiple classnames (which initially were IDs)

Comment: @mplungjan I dont know what you mean by compeltely answered the question. I don't want to argue but as per your code it will all the blocks which have the class name "abc1"

Comment: The OP wants to show a UL that have two strings to identify it onload of the page. You have provided a GIGANTIC answer, possibly hoping like others on this page, that sheer quantity will persuade OP that your answer is the better one. I have answered the question "how to find and show a UL onload based on one string, when UL is identified by two strings" which is what I believe is the real question after taking OPs comments into account.

Comment: @mplungjan Even i wanted to give a simple solution, but the OP had issues initially so it became long as i keep on editing it as per his requirement. Anyways cheers :) I love your answer too.. Keep rocking :)

Comment: If you love it, vote it up, seems someone voted it down for some strange reason

Answer (score 1):

It is not good practice - even illegal to have IDs separated by comma - change to class with spaces instead and do

```
$(function() {
  var text = "abc1"; // passed somehow
  $("."+text).show();
});
```

If you want to have a function you can use later, try this which will hide all ULs and show the one(s) with the passed className

```
function toggleULs(text) {
  $("ul").hide(); // or other selector
  $("."+text).show();
}

$(function() {
  var text = "abc1"; // passed somehow
  toggleULs(text); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on my understanding of the problem I created a fiddle to provide my solution. Please check out the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/C73SZ/). I hope it helps.

```
var toggleShowHide=function(classname){
    $('.'+classname).toggle();
};

toggleShowHide('abc1');
```

Comment: @mplungjan I understand this has been answered but I don't understand why most of the answers have show() in them when the question is specifically to toggle show/hide functionality. I also mentioned "my solution" in my answer so that the questioner can pick the best of the answers provided.

Comment: @mplungjan Please read the question again. It clearly says "How to toggle display block or none based on a string I have onload?".

Comment: I have not voted your answer down - no problem making a toggle function. I even added one myself - No worries

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML :

```
<ul id="test1,test2" style="display:none;"> 
<li><a href="#" onclick="myfunction('users')">My Link</a></li> 
</ul>

<ul id="abc1,abc2" style="display:none;"> 
<li><a href="#" onclick="myfunction('users')">My Link</a></li> 
</ul>
```

Is not correct, According [W3c HTML4 documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id) following characters are allowed in ID attribute.

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be
>   followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"),
>   underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

Your Question:

> **Is it possible to achive with class="test1 test2" and based on this can i get ul id and toggle it ? If id cannot have multiple values.**

Yes, you can assign multiple class. But don't use comma to separate two class, instead of comma use [`space`](http://css-tricks.com/multiple-class-id-selectors/) to separate two classes

Try this :

HTML:

```
 <ul id="firstUL" class="test1 test2" style="display:none;"> 
    <li><a href="#" onclick="myfunction('users')">My Link 1</a></li> 
    </ul>

    <ul id="secondUL" class="abc1 abc2" style="display:none;"> 
    <li><a href="#" onclick="myfunction('users')">My Link 2</a></li> 
    </ul>

<ul id="thirdUL" class="another1 another2" style="display:none;"> 
    <li><a href="#" onclick="myfunction('users')">My Link 3</a></li> 
    </ul>
```

Jquery:

```
$('ul.abc1.abc2, ul.test1.test2').show();
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/6bfWe/1/)

[Example With toggle](http://jsfiddle.net/6bfWe/1/)

Comment: @mohamedrias: Yes, But i added some more specification for this and also added a example with .toggle() :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul id="test1" style="display:none;"> // it is not good practice to have 2 id value. 
   <li><a href="#">My Link</a></li> 
</ul>


  var ulID = $("ul").attr("id"); // get the ID of ul on page load

        if($("#" + ulID).css("display", "none")) // check the status of ID and open accordingly
            {
                $("#" + ulID).css("display", "block"); 
            }
        else
            {
                 $("#" + ulID).css("display", "none");
            }
```